# Blur as adjustment layer?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, blur

An adjustment layer changes only the *appearance* of the layers below it without affecting those lower layers. For example, all color layers below a black-and-white adjustment layer will look black and white, and when I paint a red line on such a color layer it will appear as if I am drawing a gray line, but when I turn the black-and-white adjustment layer off, I will see the color layer with its red line. So I can work with colors, while seeing their greyscale values.

In the same way I would like to have a "blur layer", that will make everything below it *appear* blurred, while the actual layers remain crisp and sharp.

I would like to work on an image while seeing it blurred, but then be able to turn off the blur and have a sharp image.

Comment: Not exactly the same as what you describe, but the best possible alternative  would be a [Smart filter](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/applying-smart-filters.html)

Comment: Well not exactly. It becomes sort of like a document within document. The contents of that smart filter layer are still there, they are just not as accessible. You can edit the contents if you right click the layer and choose "Edit contents" or double click the layer thumbnail. That opens the contents in a new document. When that document is saved, the work document that houses the smart filter layer gets updated.

Comment: @Joonas It seems that this makes it impossible to paint in the blurred view, because I would have to work in the smartobject layer in a different window, where the content of the smartobject doesn't appear blurred. Right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: @Joonas And I guess it's not somehow possible to apply the smartobject layer including its filters to the layer(s) below it?

Comment: Yea, it's not possible.

Comment: @Joonas That's a shame. Thank's anyway. At least I learned about smart filters :-)

Comment: There is another alternative I came up with specifically for what you are after... Not sure if it makes sense, but as I was trying to think of ways to get close to what you want and so what if your brush with a blurred (hardness 0) brush and use a levels or curves adjustment layer to make it sharp again?so essentially same thing in reverse? I should add that it also has its flaws...

Comment: Thank you, @Joonas, but that won't work for me. I want to use a brush with a structre, and I want to see it blurred while I paint so it doesn't irritate me when I try for a smooth transition. Working with a blurred brush and then sharpening it won't give me the same detailed structure I have when I paint directly with it. I guess I'll just have to take off my glasses to see everything out of focus ;-)